# How to bring circlemarker on front in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have two `circlemarkers`, A and B, at the same place

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tE3aU/)

I'd like marker B to move to the front when I select marker A, and vice versa.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the methods `bringToFront()` and `bringToBack()`, as noted here in the Leaflet API: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Marker instead CircleMarker you can use the riseOnHover option doing:

```
var marker = L.marker(cordinate, {riseOnHover: true});      
marker.addTo(map);
```

**I know it's not exactly the question, but this tip can help someone.**